# Get current playing track info from Microsoft Groove Music app

Tags: c#, audio-player, groove

I would like to get track info of the current playing track in the Microsoft Groove app in my own app. I'm talking about the Groove APP and not the REST Api.

My first approach was to try and get the `Windows.Media.Playback.BackgroundMediaPlayer` (now obsolete) info from my own process (app). More info about the `Windows.Media.Playback.BackgroundMediaPlayer` in the [Dev Center Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer)

The idea was to get information from `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current` but this only works in the same process. And again, this is obsolete anyway, now MS recommends using the `Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer` class, but this is also only accessible in the same process where the MediaPlayer is used.

Second approach would be getting the information from the [System Media Transport Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/integrate-with-systemmediatransportcontrols).

For those not familiar with the SMTC, here's what I'm talking about (the little popup when you skip/play/pause from your keyboard for example):

[image]

The article about SMTC linked above shows how to use those controls in your app, the thing I want to do is basically the exact opposite.

Does anyone have an other approach you think might work?

*edit*

So I found out that it might be possible by using the native `ISystemMediaTransportControlsInterop` interface:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn892315(v=vs.85).aspx

more exactly the `ISystemMediaTransportControlsInterop::GetForWindow` method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn892316(v=vs.85).aspx

But I don't know how to call this method, what library to use (dll) so i can (maybe) pInvoke this in my C# app.

The docs say that this is included in the Windows 10 SDK, but I can't find out where.

Maybe I'm totally wrong and maybe I can't use this in C# (because it is a C++ interface). But my idea was that this must be compiled into a library and that I can use it by using pInvoke.

It would be much appreciated if someone can explain this to me.

Comment: @apocalypse, again, I'm not talking about the Groove REST API, please read my post again. I'm talking about the current playing track info, which the Groove REST API knows nothing about. The REST API is only to look up information about *any* song in the Groove library, not the track info of the song you are playing in the Groove app.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this at last?

Comment: I tried to do the same, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222833/get-systemmediatransportcontrols-for-other-window/62310172#62310172

Comment: Late to the party, but I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63099881/13997827

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls

`SystemMediaTransportControls _control = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();`

Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd is the contract you require to gain access to the SMTC Class.

Reference this and you should be able to gain control.

`<Reference Include="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"> <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\3‌​.0.0.0\Windows.Found‌​ation.UniversalApiCo‌​ntract.winmd</HintPa‌​th> </Reference>`

add this to your project file in visual studio.

I'm hoping this is what you were looking for, either way this will allow you access to the "Windows.Media" namespace.