# Why can't pip find winrt?

Tags: python, command-line, pip, windows-runtime

I just bought a new laptop and I'm trying to set it up with python. I am using python 3.10.0, windows 10, pip v21.3. For the most part, pip seems to be working correctly, I've already used it to install multiple packages such as pygame. When I try to install winrt, however, I get this error

```
C:\Users\matth>pip install winrt
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winrt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for winrt
```

My old laptop is still able to uninstall and reinstall winrt using pip without a problem, and again pip works on my new laptop for other packages, just not winrt. Any idea what the problem is and how I fix it?

Comment: What version(s) of Python do you have installed? [`winrt`](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/) appears only to support Python 3.7, 3.8, or 3.9.

Comment: 3.10. That makes a lot of sense, as my old laptop still only has 3.9. Any idea how to get around this/when they will update?

Comment: How to get around it: use Python 3.9 instead of 3.10. When they'll update, I have no idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Microsoft has not been maintaining the `winrt` package. There is no binary wheel for Python 3.10 as seen [on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/#files). There is also a [request](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues/763) for this on GitHub.

I have started a community-maintained fork of the [PyWinRT](https://github.com/pywinrt) project. You can install and use [winsdk](https://pypi.org/project/winsdk/) instead. It supports Python 3.10. Just replace `winrt` with `winsdk` in your imports.

A list of improvements and bug fixes compared to the `winrt` package can be found in the [changelog](https://github.com/pywinrt/pywinrt/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: I think this answer is deprecated since it seem microsoft start to maintaining winrt there are packages available at https://pypi.org/project/winrt/#files

Comment: The last release from Microsoft was from February 2021 and, as of April 2022, the [xlang repository](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/) has been archived (made read-only) so clearly Microsoft is not planning on making any updates any time soon.

Answer (score -3):

Your new laptop may have an old CPU and winrt may not have been compiled for that CPU. Check the model of your CPU.