# Python winrt how to get notification listener permission?

Tags: python, notifications, windows-runtime

How is it possible to get needed permission for a notification listener from winrt in python? The following code immediately returns "denied" without any sort of windows prompt showing up:

```py
import asyncio
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications.management as management

async def main():
    listener = management.UserNotificationListener.current
    access_result = await listener.request_access_async()
    print(access_result) #prints 2: denied

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Naturally then it is impossible to do anything useful with the notification listener which is a problem.

I ran this code from cmd with python 3.11.4 and [winrt 2.0.0b2](https://pypi.org/project/winrt-Windows.UI.Notifications.Management/)

The docs mention adding the permission to the manifest for c# apps, but how would this work for winrt-python?

Comment: I've ran your code using winsdk instead of winrt which doesn't want to install (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095029/403671) in C# and in python and it gives me back 1 (Allowed). I'm running Windows 11

Comment: @SimonMourier I wonder if there's some notification permission I set years ago on windows that preempts even asking for the permission? I can't find anything to that effect. I'm also running windows 10 22h2 if that's important. I'll try the older `winsdk` version of winrt in case it was somehow compiled differently when I get home..

Comment: I've tested a Windows 10 22H2 in hyper-v and it also works fine. Note I've not used https://pypi.org/project/winrt-Windows.UI.Notifications.Management/ (I have install problems with it) but winsdk instead. Not sure it changes anything (it works with C# always too)

Comment: @SimonMourier identical behavior with winsdk 1.0.0b10: immediately denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this maybe should have been over on another stack exchange because the solution was indeed just finding the windows setting buried in the menu: Privacy > Notifications > User notification access

> [image]

You have to evidently turn on the option to allow you to turn on the feature (created by the department of redundancy department I'm sure).