# Scraping media info thumbnail in windows

Tags: python

`_winsdk_Windows_Storage_Streams.IRandomAccessStream.open_read_async()` gets stuck.

I am trying to extract the media info thumbnail in windows and store it as a regular image file, using Python.

```
import winsdk.windows.media.control as wmc
import asyncio
from winsdk.windows.storage.streams import DataReader, Buffer, InputStreamOptions

async def __getMediaSession():
    sessions = await wmc.GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.request_async()
    session = sessions.get_current_session()
    return session

async def __get_media_info():
    current_session = await __getMediaSession()
    if current_session:
        info = await current_session.try_get_media_properties_async()

        info_dict = {song_attr: info.__getattribute__(song_attr) for song_attr in dir(info) if song_attr[0] != '_'}

        info_dict['genres'] = list(info_dict['genres'])

        return info_dict
    raise Exception('TARGET_PROGRAM is not the current media session')

async def read_stream_into_buffer(stream_ref, buffer):
    readable_stream = await stream_ref.open_read_async()
    readable_stream.read_async(buffer, buffer.capacity, InputStreamOptions.READ_AHEAD)


thumb_stream_ref = asyncio.run(__get_media_info())['thumbnail']

thumb_read_buffer = Buffer(5000000)
asyncio.run(read_stream_into_buffer(thumb_stream_ref, thumb_read_buffer))

buffer_reader = DataReader.from_buffer(thumb_read_buffer)
byte_buffer = buffer_reader.read_bytes(thumb_read_buffer.length)

with open('icon.jpg', 'wb+') as f:
    f.write(bytearray(byte_buffer))
```

This is my current approach and it's heavily based on [Collecting Media/'Now Playing' information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037406). (and yes I know that I should ask question regarding another post over there, but I simply don't have enough reputation on StackOverflow, yet :( ) But I'm having problems with this line:

```
readable_stream = await stream_ref.open_read_async()
```

It simply never finishes, although no exception is raised.

Has anyone experienced this before or is able to help?

Python version is 3.10.3, if that's helpful.

Comment: There's a syntax error in the `asyncio.run` line -- there's an unmatched closed paren.

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed and corrected the error. But that was just a copy-paste mistake by me and has nothing to with the actual error.

Comment: I figured that.  If you print `thumb_stream_ref`, what do you see?  What type does it show?

Comment: <_winsdk_Windows_Storage_Streams.IRandomAccessStreamReference object at 0x000001926F1280D0>

Answer (score 0):

```
thumb_stream_ref = asyncio.run(__get_media_info())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).