# "Access is denied" in Windows.Media.Control GSMTCSM

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to create an app that reads the current Windows audio session. I have found the `GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager` (GSMTCSM), which seemed promising, however, I ran into two issues:

1. Console App cannot call any `Windows.Media` APIs, it just says that the solution is not found. This was not solved by simply installing `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` - it did nothing. I still could not access the `Windows.Media` namespace. Only after creating a UWP app I could access it
2. Already in UWP app, I only tried to request the manager, like this (I know it's messy - just a test)

   ```cs
   GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync().AsTask().Wait();
   ```

   But this throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied'` error (no more info is displayed). I do not know what is causing this. I already added the `musicLibrary` capability (in fact - all available out of desperation) and ran VS as Adminstrator, but none of this stopped the error.

I did find [this script](https://github.com/keifufu/WebNowPlaying-Rainmeter/blob/main/src/WNPReduxAdapterLibraryExtensions/WNPReduxNative.cs) which does use GSMTCSM (renamed to `SessionManager`), but after cloning the repository, I could not event compile it. This is most likely caused by the same issue that caused my issue #1.

TL;DR: I want to read the data (title, artist, etc.) and control the state (play, pause, shuffle) of currently playing audio on the host computer (excluding browsers). Preferably not inside a UWP, but that's a minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. At VS2017 it couldnt even find Windows.Media.Control namespace. Try to write your program at VS2022 and use SDK published at this October. Set the correct version of Win at application properties.
[app properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiPwP.jpg)I add only SDK from nuGet to references.

Working app at link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlSEnJ1CkG5blY0RIayJVJSLImC-cw?e=hFVwCL

Source of up code: [Using SystemMediaTransportControls to get current playing song info from other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580053/using-systemmediatransportcontrols-to-get-current-playing-song-info-from-other-a)

In cace of no active player it throw System.NullReferenceException at 22 line of code
[no active player exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY10x.jpg) at other its correct.
[all OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASEL7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

add the globalMediaControl capability to your package manifest

```
<Capabilities>
    <uap7:Capability Name="globalMediaControl"/>
</Capabilities>
```