# Get SystemMediaTransportControls for other window

Tags: uwp, com, windows-10, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm interesting in [ISystemMediaTransportControlsInterop::GetForWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mediatransport/isystemmediatransportcontrolsinterop-getforwindow) method. The documentation is outdated for it. But I have found files *SystemMediaTransportControlsInterop.h* and *SystemMediaTransportControlsInterop.idl* in folder *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um* of Windows SDK. They are describing `GetForWindow` method. So, how can I get an instance of `ISystemMediaTransportControlsInterop` and call this method?

WinRT contains only method [SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.getforcurrentview?view=winrt-19041), but I want to get an instance of `SystemMediaTransportControls` for other program from my application.

Thank you

Comment: The documentation isn't outdated. The content isn't being updated regularly. That does not imply that the documentation were inaccurate. I'm not sure what the issue is now.

Comment: Only the process that owns the window can get/create its SMTC. It is not intended for you to manipulate the SMTC that belongs to other windows. This is implied by GetForCurrentView, since the current view is defined as the view associated with the current thread, which is naturally also part of the calling process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found, that *WinRT* is based on *COM* technology. And we can get `ActivationFactory` to call method from interop interface.
For example, on C#:

```
[Guid("ddb0472d-c911-4a1f-86d9-dc3d71a95f5a")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIInspectable)]
public interface ISystemMediaTransportControlsInterop
{
    SystemMediaTransportControls GetForWindow(IntPtr Window, [In] ref Guid riid);
}

var smtcInterop = (ISystemMediaTransportControlsInterop)WindowsRuntimeMarshal.GetActivationFactory(typeof(SystemMediaTransportControls));
var guid = typeof(SystemMediaTransportControls).GUID;
var smtc = smtcInterop.GetForWindow(hwnd, ref guid);
```

But the problem is, that I receive access denied exception if I try *SMTC* instance of other window.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to use this API *at all*. Could you help me with some more details about your code sample? Where can I find the missing types?

Comment: What exactly types do you need?

Comment: My scenario is to control my media player (custom app, Windows Forms) from the Bluetooth headset controls (works with Firefox/YouTube, play/pause, prev/next, volume up/down).

Comment: @ygoe I think [GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssessionmanager?view=winrt-19041) is what you need. It allows control global media.